# Infinite Redirect Loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS caused by implementing URL Rewrite module on IIS 6

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-6, http-redirect

I am getting an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on implementing the following URL Rewrite rule,

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="http to https Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I have cleared the browser cookies and restarted the site on IIS 6 as well and it simply keeps flipping into http and https on every refresh.

I have also un-ticked the require SSL in SSL setting.

Any idea why this is happening and how to remedy this situation?

Comment: That usually means something from within your site is trying to redirect HTTPS back to HTTP. Please learn failed request tracing and analyze further.

Answer (score 0):

SSL wasn't setup correctly on the server, hence, falling back onto http and forth to https by the rule, hence, causing an infinite loop.  Fixed the SSL implementation and it now works right.